# How to add to a 'time' type in MySQL with JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I know how to 'SET' it, but how can I add to it? Such as...

```
    // Add 1 minute to the current 'time' object
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        String sql = "UPDATE Table "
                   + "SET 'Time Field' = 'Time Field' + ? "
                   + "WHERE 'User Column' = 'Random Name'";
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setTime(0, new Time(60000));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm sure I have to use the "ADDITEM(expr1,expr2)" function, but how exactly would I do so? I feel like it's not as easy as just typing it into my String.

Comment: This probably isn't a complete answer, but parameter indexes in JDBC start with 1, not 0, so your `statement.setTime` call should use `1`, not `0`. Separately, are you sure you should have those single quotes around `Time Field` and `User Column`? I thought MySQL used backticks.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Quotes (') are the standard syntax for literal values in all versions of SQL (Oracle, DB2, MySQL, SQL Server etc etc).  MySQL backticks are different...  And yes, variables in prepared statements should start at "1", not "0".

Comment: @paulsm4: but the single quotes are wrong in that statement as those are column names, *not* string literals (except for `'Random Name'`).

Comment: @paulsm4: Single quotes are standard for *string literals*, yes; not for *object names*. His `Time Field` and such are object names (column names, in this case), which is exactly what backticks are used to escape (in case you want to use spaces or reserved words in the names).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pass in a Java date/time: you should use a SQL time/date literal, or a MySQL time/date function.  Either way, you no longer need a "time" variable in your prepared statement:

```
// EXAMPLE: add 2 hours to current time
String sql = 
  "UPDATE Table " + 
  "SET 'Time Field' = 'Time Field' + DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) " +
  "WHERE 'User Column' = 'Random Name'";
```

Here are the available MySql date/time functions:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Use PreparedStatement class. The documantation is here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score -1):

Use `ADDTIME()` function as below:

```
         String sql = "UPDATE Table "
               + "SET 'Time Field' = ADDTIME('Time Field', ?) "
               + "WHERE 'User Column' = 'Random Name'";
```

Then set the param value with desired value.

Comment: I was hoping it wasn't such an obvious answer, but thanks. I was kind of nervous to use the ADDTIME() method after I read about what it returns, but I'll go ahead and try it now.

Comment: No.  "addtime()" is OK.  Getting the time from the client, in Java, is generally *not* the way to go.  If you're doing a *relative* time, then you should get the time from the *server*.  If you *must* get time from the client, then you should convert it to a date/time string (e.g. "2:00 am", or "2012-11-04 2:00am").  Look it up.  Or think about it.  IMHO...

Comment: @user1570575: I updated another version. Please  check and let me know, if doesn't work.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please leave some helpful comment to help understand the issue in the answer.

Comment: Well I'm actually keeping track of "Run Time" rather than the current date. Is that a factor that I'm taking care of by using 'time' rather than 'date'?

Comment: @user1570575: Yes. Use Time/ADDTIME. I will delete the ADDDATE from my answer as that is bit confusing. `The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.`

Comment: Okay thanks. When I got to the part of where I declare a new Time(millseconds), I got worried about that. I think I have it all taken care of now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1570575 Good to know. If you think its helpful, please don't forget to accept the answer.